# Matlab, Inkscape, ConTeXt and automatic image conversion?

Tags: conversion, context, svg

I want to use matlab plots in my ConTeXt document, but preprocess them in Inkscape. I wonder if there is some recommended workflow.

So far what I'm doing is this:

1. save matlab figure as 'fig', so I can reuse the figure in matlab. Just in case
2. use plot2svg to create a SVG from matlab (actually I've patched the original to gzip the svg.)
3. edit plot in Inkscape
4. Here is one of my problems: use edited plot ConTeXt

I'm using MkII (pdfTex), since I have had some problems(with layout, no euler font and others) with MkIV(which actually supports SVG) and I think it is still beta.

I want to import the gzipped SVG directly in my ConTeXt document, but see no way how to import the document. The method mentioned in the wiki does not work either. Is there a way to convert the file automatically with Inkscape to e.g. pdf?

Maybe my workflow is not the best for the task, so I also wonder if there is a better way to create, edit and use figures/plots in my documents.

Comment: What sort of edits do you do with Inkscape?  It's difficult to make suggestions without knowing this.

Comment: It depends. Removing lines (e.g. Axes), adding arrows to the end of the axes, adding text, change color/style/line-width of plots, adding arrows with annotations, putting plots together (with additional text, lines, arrows, whatever).

Comment: Off topic: Euler works seamlessly with MkIV. Just use Neo Euler OpenType Math fonts.

Comment: To use an SVG image in ConTeXt, you have to convert it to pdf. MkIV does the conversion for you (using inkscape). If you want to do the same in MkII, you can tweak the example on the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes#Running_external_commands_once)

Comment: Since you are editing the SVG in Inkscape anyway, why you don't just save it as PDF (which is what MkIV is doing behind the scenes),

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but [rubber](http://rubber.sf.net) should be extensible to the point of handling all conversions you need automatically (by calling external commands), based on scanning source files for file inclusin patterns and checking whether those files are up-to-date. I use it routinely for eps->pdf conversion, or {jpg,png}->eps when compiling into dvi.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make matlab output plots without axes? This would save you a step, no?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: to convert an image from SVG to PDF using Inkscape, you can use this command line:

```
$ inkscape --export-pdf=<image>.pdf <image>.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

It might improve the pdf generation process if using [Ipe](http://tclab.kaist.ac.kr/ipe/) and a related tool [svg2ipe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipe7/files/tools/). I would strip down all the plot details (Axis, legend etc.) and leave only the data and then ship it to Ipe and modify things over there. (A little bit of a personal thing though)

Other than saving my life a few times I think the natural Latex support is quite handy. For the experts of Lua, one can dive right in to the inner core. But how I wish it could read .eps files generated by Matlab or even .fig files.